# How to serve React app AND Django blog from Nginx?

Tags: django, reactjs, nginx

I'm using nginx to serve a React app from my domain root `/` and a Django blog app from `/blog`. I'm also using nginx to redirect all `http` to `https`.

The problem is some weird behaviour... If I navigate to the blog with a clear cache, it shows the blog. If I then navigate to the index page it shows the react app. All good so far. But *then*, if I return to `/blog` it continues to show the react app, not the blog! I think the problem involves caching, but I'm not sure where.

I am not using react-router, so I'm not sure how the urls could get redirected on the client side.

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    root /production_build;

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/mysite;
    }

    location /blog {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://upstream_django_server;
    }

    location /cms {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://upstream_django_server;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you hit the `/blog` the second time, what does the nginx access log show?

Comment: @Tarun The second time I go to /blog the nginx log only shows a successful (code 200) GET request to /api (part of my nginx config, similar to blog and cms), which is called by my react app. Hence, I guess this indicates the browser is not passing the second /blog request to the server. Why?

Comment: Try disabling the react worked process and see what happens in that case?

Comment: There is no react worker as it is a bundle served with nginx. However, if I simply remove the `location /` section (giving default nginx page instead of react) navigation works fine.

Comment: What does the chrome network tab show for the second blog request in the response data?

Comment: On first access to /blog I only see `/blog` but on second access after react app I also see api request and service-worker.js as you suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174114/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-zg101).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should disable the service worker in react, as it is interfering with your `/blog` url and returning its own response the next time.

Since you are mixing 2 apps here, you don't want to take a risk of having something which is difficult to get rid of.

Service workers can be sometimes very nasty because of caching responses